# insert data to SQL with default data

Tags: php, sql

I set 3 columns: id(auto increment), names, age(default = 15).
Now if I want to insert data to SQL I can use this below line:

```sql
INSERT INTO shoppinglist (name,age) VALUES(?,?)
```

The first ? = alex and second ? = 22
which will find in the database that the id=1, the name=alex and age=22

Now what I want that if the user inserts only the name without the age, I would like from the age to get the default value, like if the user insert only the name with David, and submit it, I would like to e in DB like id=2 name =David age=15(default)

So is there a way to make the age to get the default if the user didn't insert the age or the age was 0?

Comment: If user inserts only name, use `INSERT INTO shoppinglist (name) VALUES (?)` and supply only the name for `?`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you didn't get my point, your way if the user insert only the name, I need if the user insert the name and the age, then it will be inserted as they did, if they insert only the name, it will be inserted the name only and the age will be the default

Comment: @Lory . . . Use an `if` in your application code.  If the user provides a valid age, then `insert` both columns.  Otherwise insert only one.

Answer (score 1):

```
create shoppinglist (
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`age` int default 15
)
```

when you make the insertion, it would be like this:

```
INSERT INTO shoppinglist (name) VALUES ("Alex");
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO shoppinglist VALUES (Null, "Alex", DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you didn't get my point, your way if the user insert only the name, I need if the user insert the name and the age, then it will be inserted as they did, if they insert only the name, it will be inserted the name only and the age will be the default

Comment: Oooh ok ok, I'm sorry, I understood, so don't you think that when inserting with php, it would be easier for you to verify if (age !="null"), and so you can execute one of two different insert querys?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO shoppinglist (name) VALUES(?)
```

this query inserts just name and puts the default value 15 for the age

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFNULL` function in query:

```
INSERT INTO shoppinglist (name,age) VALUES(?, IFNULL(?, 15));
```

The PHP code may look as:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO shoppinglist (name,age) VALUES(?, IFNULL(?, 15));";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(['Alex', 30]);
$stmt->execute(['Jane', null]);
```

[PHP PDO online fiddle](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/2fd224376d7184f00c824434699c357d/php/php8/8249a76a5327e0aa2ed2f5dc0ba6a81e/)